# Timestamp columns not stored as what timezone I desired

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, yii

I have a quick question... I have a table with timestamp column... I set the mysql's timezone to UTC by querying this line

> SET time_zone = '+00:00'

but the timestamp column is still stored using my machine's current timezone... is this a bug or something? im using Yii php framework for storing of data and Phpmyadmin to see the data

This is the complete scenario

1) I have a table that have 6 columns(id,post_hash,user_id,post_msg,post_time,update_time)

2) post_time and update_time is both timestamps...

3) but update_time has an attribute where in it gonna update itself when the row had a modification. and post_time is just a plain timestamp column

4) the problem when i insert a data... the post_time and update_time follows the current timezone of my computer, but I already set the timezone of my mysql and php to UTC before executing the SQL.

this is my Yii code

```
    $conn = Yii::app()->db;
    //Store the message to database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts(post_hash,user_id,post_msg,post_time)
            VALUES(:post_hash,:user_id,:post_msg,:post_time)";

    $dbcmd = $conn->createCommand($sql);
    $user_id = Yii::app()->user->user_id;
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $post_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
    $post_hash = "p-".Ynet_Crypt::encryptString(time().Yii::app()->user->username,"sha256");
    $dbcmd->bindParam(":post_hash",$post_hash);
    $dbcmd->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id);
    $dbcmd->bindParam(":post_msg",$msg);
    $dbcmd->bindParam(":post_time",$post_date);
    $dbcmd->execute();
```

and this is my yii configuration that sets my mysql connection to be UTC timezone

```
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'initSQLs'=>array("SET time_zone = '+00:00'"),
    ),
```

**All I want is the datetime I stored will be UTC**

Comment: How did you determine what form the column was stored in?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't quite understand your question. please explain further thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the time that you are INSERT-ing or UPDATE-ing in your query is not offset by a timezone?

Comment: @Mahan: You say the column is still stored using your machine's current timezone. I'm asking how you established how the columns were stored. What process did you follow? (Are you sure they are stored incorrectly? Maybe they are stored correctly and you are just retrieving/viewing them incorrectly. That's what I'm trying to get at.)

Comment: my computer is in +8 UTC and my target timezone is UTC... is my computer being +8 UTC causes the offset?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I retrieve them using phpmyadmin...

Comment: Give us a complete example. The values you insert, how you insert them, the values that are stored, how you view them and the values that you'd expect instead.

Answer (score 1):

To synchronize both PHP and mySQL timezone together, you can add this code on your config/main.php file`

```
'timeZone' => 'UTC'//This is for PHP
'db'=>array(
'charset' => 'utf8',
'initSQLs'=>array("SET time_zone = '+00:00'"),
 ),
```

`

and now you can also use `CDbExpression ('NOW()')` to get the current datetime from the system on your desired timezone.